# Sort string-array according to given input values and set it into spinner accordingly

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've set string-array of resource into Spinner. The string-array is like below,

```
<string-array name="gender">
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
    </string-array>
```

The first element showing into Spinner "Male" and second "Female". Now i want to change this order as "Female" value first and "Male" value second if my input value is "Female".

Kindly tell me how to sort as above mentioned order.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values in onItemSelected as follows :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                       // if value is Female
                       String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender); 
                       Arrays.sort(list);
                       // set the sorted list back again into the spinner adapter     
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
```